# Prepended auto-prefixed css variables in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, autoprefixer

Is there a way to set css-auto-prefixer in Visual Studio Code to prepend the auto-prefixed css values rather than append them?

When I type in a prefix-able property, such as `border-radius` the auto-prefixer adds `-webkit-border-radius` (as expected).  But it appends it to the list and when a browser like Firefox goes through the list of properties, it ends up using the -webkit version since it came last.

```
border-radius: .5rem;
-webkit-border-radius: .5rem;
```

As it is a cascading style sheet, one would think the unprefixed current property should come last and the retro properties first.

```
-webkit-border-radius: .5rem;
border-radius: .5rem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Type it like this:

`-bdrs` and then when you choose `border-radius` from the sugggestions, the vendor prefixes will be completed before the un-prefixed version.  So start the property with the dash `-` to get that functionality.

This is literally the example from the documentation:  see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_include-vendor-prefixes.

---

If you don't want to use emmet abbreviations, look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sporiley.css-auto-prefix or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-autoprefixer

Comment: Sounds like I would need to learn the Emmet abbreviations, as trying the -border-radius version didn't open a suggestion box, whereas -bdrs did.  Or simply edit the output, since I only maintain one website for my business.